# Is there a hide/show column functionality on jqGrid like in flexigrid?

Tags: jqgrid, flexigrid

Is there a hide/show column functionality on jqGrid like in flexigrid? I want the user be capable of hiding columns, so it will be easy for them to review related columns(informations)

Comment: Probably [ColumnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) is what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out hideCol() and showCol()

```
$('#tblId').hideCol('column');

$('#tblId').showCol('column');
```

Instead of the column name you can use the column index, too.

But I haven't seen this feature implemented (e.g. selecting from the header directly).

Answer (score 0):

```
JQGrid1.Columns.FromDataField(ColumnName).Visible = false;
```